# How to catch Chrome field validation error event

Tags: javascript, html, validation, google-chrome

I use the HTML5 form field type 'email'. Chrome will validate the field's value on submit and notify the user visually with a tooltip message in case of an error.
At the same time I've attached a JS plugin to the submit button which disables it on submit and changes the text into "Logging in ...".

How do I catch the event in case of an validation alert/error?
I need this in order to enable the Submit button again.

kind regards,
Bart

**Edit:**
So I found a way to disable the validation: stackoverflow.com/questions/3090369/… But still the question remains: is there a way to catch the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen on the `invalid` event or set the `oninvalid` attribute. It will kick in when you're trying to submit the form but validation on the element fails.

```
function listener(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browsers default behavior
    console.log(event); // log the generated event
}

var input = document.getElementById('number');
input.addEventListener('invalid', listener);
```

[Demonstrated on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kawQ/)